# Default button set but not working

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0

In my asp.net webform i have a criteria when the user enter the driver name in a text box and press enter all the contact details of the driver is displayed in the grid below

As there is no  keypress event i use defaultbutton property to do so 
my code looks like

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p>
    <br />
</p>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Driver Name :</td>
            <td class="style7">

            <asp:Panel Id="panel2" runat="server" DefaultButton="bt1">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDrivername" runat="server" Width="153px"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button id="bt1" Text="Default" runat="server" onclick="bt1_Click" />

            </td></tr> </table>
```

And in my code behind i write a function to fetch data >but the debugger doesnot enter the  bt1_Click() > I am a new bie to web development and I am sure there may be some mistake from my part can anyone point it out.........I am using Web form with master page

Comment: Are you expecting that button's click event to fire when the user presses ENTER?

Comment: Yes I am Doing the same

Comment: And so when you're focused on the `txtDrivername` control and press ENTER it doesn't post back and fire the `bt1_Click` event? Does it post back?

Comment: It postback but it never enter the bt1_Click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code looks right except that the `onclick`:

```
<asp:Button id="bt1" Text="Default" runat="server" onclick="bt1_Click" />
```

isn't cased right:

```
<asp:Button id="bt1" Text="Default" runat="server" OnClick="bt1_Click" />
```

so setting that properly should hook up the event handler.